# Exporting metrics in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, codahale-metrics

spring boot shows all the possible metrics in `/metrics` endpoint. on the other hand, internally it uses metrics exporters. for example when you add dropwizard metrics (current de facto standard?) it gets registered automatically but not all spring-boot metrics are exported to dropwizard. in order to have more/all metrics, one has to manually register different metric sets. and it has to be maintained in parallel to what spring-boot does for `/metrics` endpoint.

so the question is: how it should be done properly? should i use metrics exporters and maintain it for each of dozens microservices or use `Collection<PublicMetrics>` used by `/metrics` endpoint and maintained by spring?

Answer (score 0):

Use only dropwizard metrics to instrument your code since it has a more intuitive API then the Spring.

With the spring-dropwizard (http://metrics.ryantenney.com/) integration, all dropwizard metrics are getting exposed to the endpoint /metrics, so you do not need to register anything manually.